# SQL How do I sum up many records key:value pairs?

Tags: php, sql

I need to obtain the sum of many values with the same key from a SQL Query.
For example...say I have 30 rows returned from a Query and they look like this.

```
1) (a:2), (b:4),(f:1), (h:3)
2) (c:2), (f:4),(t:1), (z:3)
3) (a:5), (b:2),(s:1), (z:3)
4) (d:2), (g:4),(s:1), (t:3)
and so on....
```

What I need to do is sum up all the "a" and all the "b" and all the "c" etc
And put all that into an array or object so I can access them for later processing.

$total = [(a:7),(b:6),(c:2),(d:2).....(z:6)];

Is there a way to do this all from SQL?   Or do I have to sum all these records externally using PHP for example?

This is my SQL code to obtain the 30 records...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
$queryActivity = "SELECT activity, count(activity) FROM users u, activities_users au, activities a WHERE ($row[zip] = u.zip AND u.id = au.user_id AND au.activity_id = a.id) GROUP BY a.activity";
$rs2 = mysql_query($queryActivity);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) { 
echo "<tr><td>$row2[0]</td><td>";
echo "<tr><td>$row2[1]</td><td>";}
```

It returns all the activities and the sum of those activities for a certain zipcode.  I just need to total all the sums up for each activity.

Comment: You mean like a combination of `SUM` and `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: 1,2,3,4 - are these rows? Is it one column per ROW or 4 columns per row?

Comment: 1,2,3,4 are rows.....4 columns per row in my example. In actual use, it can be 30 rows with up to 170 columns each with a unique key.  Some rows may have one column and some could have up to 170 columns.  And anything in between for other rows.  Complex query huh?

Comment: Let me clarify a bit more....So right now I return a query set that shows the activities and the sum for ONE zipcode.  Now I need to do the same for 30 MORE zipcodes....then sum all that up.   Make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

Is (a:2), (b:4)... is a row in the database?

You will need to use some sort of split, SUM, and GROUP BY's.  It will be hard to help until we have more information.

So here is a quick query that will group by the first subset of the rows.  You can do the same thing for every other subset.  I don't know of a way to do what you want to do in pure mysql.

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(activity, 1,2), 
  count(activity) 
FROM users u, activities_users au, activities a 
WHERE ($row[zip] = u.zip AND u.id = au.user_id AND au.activity_id = a.id) 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(activity, 1,2)
```

Comment: This is not a useful answer to the question, and is better suited as a comment.

Comment: Yes...those are rows in the DB.  Each row may contain zero to 170 different Key:Value pairs.  170 different keys and any number of values, all INT.  That make it clearer?

Comment: This solution by thomas_Ird does exactly what my query does.  It just returns me 30 rows as I described before.

Comment: What I need now is to add up all 30 rows and give me each key and the sum of all 30 row values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your requirement, but you can use the `SUM()` method in sql.

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table GROUP BY column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to your query after GROUP BY clause:

```
  SELECT activity, count(activity) 
    FROM users u, activities_users au, activities a 
   WHERE ($row[zip] = u.zip AND u.id = au.user_id AND au.activity_id = a.id)       
GROUP BY a.activity WITH ROLLUP
```

It will add an extra row (null, totalsum) to the result set which you need to handle in PHP.

As alternative, you can calculate it with PHP inside your while loop:

```
$total[$row2[0]] = (empty($total[$row2[0]]) ? 0 : $total[$row2[0]]) + $row2[1]
```

Comment: The WITH ROLLUP gets me closer.  It shows the total sum for each row.  But what I need is the total of each activity for all 30 rows.